# How can I force jQuery Validate to check for duplicate username in database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm coming into the middle of this project so I'm having to do a bit of re-writing because of sloppy code. I am using jQuery 1.6.1 and Validate 1.8.1.

First, here's the PHP which runs the back-end (**dbquery.php**):

```
include("../includes/dbconnection.php");
session_start();

$location='';
$action='';
if($_GET['action']=='')
    $action=$_POST['action'];
else
    $action=$_GET['action'];

if($action=='checkusername'){
    $error='';
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    // exclude denied account
    $checkuserquery=mysql_query("Select * from database_users as user LEFT OUTER JOIN  database_approval as approval on user.user_id=approval.approval_user_id  where (approval.approval_status IS NULL or approval.approval_status <> 4) and user_username='".$username."'");
    $checkuserresult=mysql_numrows($checkuserquery);
    if($checkuserresult>0) {
        $error = 'false';
    } else {
        $error = 'true';
    }
    echo $error;
}
```

I'm trying to use jQuery Validate script to query the database for existing usernames on the fly. I either get two extremes: it never works or it always spits back given username as taken.

I believe the problem is that I cannot grab the input value of the username variable. When I create `alert (username)` within `function (output)`, it returns nothing. My assumption is that `.val()` is only working when the page loads thus anything I'm typing into the input isn't working for some reason.

Here's the jQuery I've re-written and copied from sources online:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability",function(value,element){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
          url: "dbquery.php",
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          data: "action=checkusername&username="+username,
          success: function(output) {
                     return output;
         }
     });
},"Sorry, this user name is not available");

// jQuery Validation script
    $("#signup").validate( {
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                checkAvailability: true // remote check for duplicate username
            },
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Enter a username"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

I am only a beginner with jQuery but am getting my hands pretty dirty with this code. Am I on the right track or should I use `remote:` under `rules` and `username`? I've been told that the `remote` method won't work because of the dynamnic nature of the input value I'm trying to validate.

The other major problem I've been running into is making the remote error message ONLY show up when a username already exists in the database. Unfortunately, it shows up whether dbquery.php comes back as `true` or `false`. If I try an existing username, it returns `false`, then I rewrite a new username that returns `true`, the message doesn't go away. Similarly, when I write a username and it returns `true`, I still get the remote error message.

The original coder was referencing `getXMLHTTP` and using `ActiveXObject`. The method he programmed seemed a little outdated so I'm trying to make the code a little more contemporary and clean it up.

5/25 - **I am editing this to include the OLD original JavaScript code which works but is using the outdated method which I'd like to get away from (*I have since removed the following code and replaced with jQuery above*)**:

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;    
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {        
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}
//validate username
function validateUsername(username){
    var strURL="dbquery.php?action=checkusername&username="+username;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();        
    if (req) {            
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {          
                    if(req.responseText=='notavailable'){
                        document.getElementById("errorusername").style.display="block";
                        document.getElementById("errorusername").innerHTML="<div id=\"errors\"><strong>"+username+"</strong> is already taken by another user.</div>";
                        error = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        error = false;
                        document.getElementById("errorusername").style.display="none";   
                    }

                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }                
        }            
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check when the validation function is getting called, what the value of `username` is and what the value of `output` is: is it `true` or `"true"`?

I'm guessing latter: a string, so you could just do:

```
return output === "true" ? true : false; // I sincerely recommend using === here
```

Since if you `return "false";` will evaluate to `true` because it's a non-empty string - yay dynamic langauges! :/

Example with `remote`:

```
$("#signup").validate( {
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            remote: {
                url: "dbquery.php",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    action: function () {
                        return "checkusername";
                    },
                    username: function() {
                        var username = $("#username").val();
                        return username;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

To set a custom error message your PHP file must return the message instead of false, so echo `"Sorry, this user name is not available"` in your PHP file.

Comment: @frits-van-campen Firebug says it's `true` without the quotes. I've done an `alert (output)` and also get `true` without quotes. The value of the username is exactly what I type into the input, however, so no problem there anymore.

Comment: @frits-van-campen I think my main goal is to make the error message ONLY show when the value of username returns `false`. I seem to have corrected my initial problem returning `true` and `false` when needed.

Comment: So what is your current issue?

Comment: @frits-van-campen The code above constantly returns `Sorry, this user name is not available` no matter whether username returns `true` or `false`. I want it to only show when it returns `false` and disappear when it returns `true`.

Comment: Are you really really really sure it's `true` and not `"true"`? Firebug doesn't generally add quotes when it's logging a string, and I know for sure alert doesn't. Try the line I posted: `return output === "true" ? true : false;`

Comment: @frits-van-campen I'm not 100% sure, no. I added your line and it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: Ok, well I checked the validator API and you need to use 'remote'. I'll write an example.

Comment: @frits-van-campen That's frustrating. Is it basically impossible to do what I'm trying to do with Validator? I'm honestly a newb with jQuery and I thought this stuff would work great but this has been the biggest headache for me.

Comment: I've posted the example. I think this will work. The problem you have is that you're hitting the most difficult validation case possible: ajax validation. And you need to use both `remote` and a function to dynamically get the value of `username`.

Comment: That's not right .. where did `Username` come from? :S Are you sure you copied it right?

Comment: @frits-van-campen Scratch what I said before, I edited it and it works exactly as intended! Let me do more testing to be absolutely sure but I think you totally fixed my problem!!

Comment: You're welcome, be sure to approve the question so other people who might stumble upon the same problem can find the solution quickly. I'll post the solution in the other thread as well.

Comment: @frits-van-campen The only other question I need to ask if that I assumed I could use the exact same method on email as well. For some reason, `@` is turning to `%40`. It's not causing validation to fail but is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: This is because you're using `get` instead of `post`. Any values you put in a `get` will be urlencoded. You can either undo the urlencoding in PHP by using `urldecode` or switch to using `post`

Comment: @frits-van-campen Thank you for the explanation. I am SOOOOOOOOO relieved now and feel like a HUGE weight has been lifted off my shoulder. :)

Answer (score 2):

While you adding **addMethod** you should return **true** or **false** from server side.

and also that value have to be returned from addMethod.

ie something like this

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability",function(value,element){
    var parameter="action=checkusername&username="+username;
    $.ajax({
          url: "dbquery.php",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          data: parameter
          success:function(output)
                 {
                    return output
                 }
     });
},"Sorry, this user name is not available");
```

Comment: @mahesh Is your `success` answer to be used literally? Meaning, `function(output)` is literally what I should use? Or, do you mean I need to use `true` or `false`?

Comment: @Micah: its something i literally wrote. You have to return a true or false value from server and also have to return it from addMethod

Comment: @mahesh okay, i put it inside the code and it doesn't change the result. Every username I try to use is not available.

Comment: can you just alert the output inside success function. Is it returning the expected value

Comment: @mahesh I'm not sure how the write the alert! I'm still relatively new to this. Is it like this? `function alert(output)` Because that didn't seem to work.

Comment: No, just alert(output) above that return stmt

Comment: @mahesh Please forgive me for holding my hand, but do you mean like this? `success: function alert(output) { return output }`

Comment: success:function(output)
                 {                          
                    alert(output);                                                                       return output
                 }

Comment: @mahesh thank you! unfortunately, there's no change in result.

Comment: @mahesh i am getting no alert at all.

Comment: @Micah: i think which means there is some error in returning the value from the function validateUsername

Comment: @mahesh the function validateUsername doesn't exist anymore. That was from the old code that I have since removed. Are you saying I should add the function validateUsername back??

Comment: then from where you checking whether username will exist or not?

Comment: @mahesh My problem must not have been descriptive enough so I edited it. I am referencing **dbquery.php**, which is the first few lines of code. I marked it above.

Comment: @mahesh cool, progress! now every username i try to enter comes back as `true` (which I replaced for `available`).

Comment: @mahesh no, every username I try is still not available

Comment: @mahesh thank you for the progress. If you have any further suggestions to make this work, awesome. If not, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @mahesh Yes, I am returning `true` popped up on the alert, which is from `$error`. However, it still says every username is not available.

Comment: @mahesh so apparently, I need to define what `username` is in the `parameter` variable. That's a step closer but still not working right.

Comment: To check the checkAvailability is working correctly just return false from the Success function

Comment: Can you check whether you got the username correctly in dbquery.php?

Comment: @mahesh I added `return false` and the result is still the same. I am always testing to see if the a username which was previously created returns as false, and it never does. It always comes back as true, just like every other username I try.

Comment: i meant you to add success:function(output)
                 {
                    return false
                 }

Comment: @mahesh the alert that I added still shows `true` but every username I try is still "not available"

Comment: i asked after adding return false is it showing the validation error message **"Sorry, this user name is not available"**?

Comment: @mahesh Yes, that's correct, it is still showing the validation error message.

Comment: can you just check by giving **return true** . Then is it showing the validation message?

Comment: @mahesh I tried `return true`, too, and it also shows the same validation error message.

Comment: can you just remove the messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
            },
        }, section and then pls check with **return true**

Comment: @mahesh I removed the messages for username and nothing has changed. I still get the same validation error messages.

Comment: actually it should work when returning false (ie it will show errormessage) and when returning true it will hide message

Comment: First we have to make the validation to work properly then try to check for existing username

Comment: @mahesh What you typed makes sense but for some reason it's not making any difference. I updated the original jQuery code above to reflect how my code looks now on my computer here, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: lets try .. just remove $.ajax({
          url: "dbquery.php",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          data: parameter,
          success: function(output) {
                     return true;
         }
     }); and give only **return true**. Is it still showing error message?

Comment: @mahesh good idea. removed `$.ajax()` and everything within it. I then added only `return true` and nothing returned when I wrote a username. When I changed it to `return false`, the validation error messages showed up for everything I tried.

Comment: k so validation is working correctly. The same approach should be followed. ie to show error message we have to return false and to hide message we have to return true.

Comment: @mahesh everything is returning `true` when I use `$.ajax()`, whether i'm using `return true` or `return false`. But it's working normally when i don't use `$.ajax()`.

Comment: i dont know how to debug php code. But pls check whether the username is reached correctly in dbquery.php

Comment: @mahesh in my original problem above, you see 3 blocks of code. The last block of code works correctly (and is the code I will stop using when I fix this jQuery code), it returns `false` when a username is available and returns `true` when a username is not available. The PHP code must be working correctly.

Comment: yes i know the previous code is working correctly. But i think the ajax request is not working correctly. Pls check the control is reaching dbquery.php with username entered in textbox.

Comment: @mahesh Once again, I'm not sure how to check to make sure the control is reaching dbquery.php with the username in the input. :(

Comment: actually i am working in .net. I don't know how to debug php code :(

Comment: @mahesh I really appreciate everything you've done. If nothing else, I've learned several things. If I find a way to verify what you're saying, I'll make sure to leave another comment.

Comment: k.. Can you please **return $username** from dbquery.php. and can you just alert its value in success function. So we can check whether the username is reached correctly in dbquery.php

Comment: @mahesh I feel like a dummy. I know what you're asking but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: @mahesh I just thought of something so I tried it. Above `return output` I added `alert (parameter)`. The result was just `action=checkusername&username=`. Somehow, the variable `username` is not finding the value that I type into the input correctly. Thus, the username doesn't seem to be passing to dbquery.php for a proper check. Is my code wrong?

Comment: @mahesh I got it to work correctly now, I had to relocate the vars inside the `addMethod` and now the username gets passed as it should. Now that this is fixed, I still get the validation error message with any username that I try, even when the `true` and `false` values are returned properly.

Comment: @mahesh i changed the original code block up at the top to reflect the change.

Comment: can you just change the success function likethis            success: function (output,status) {
                        alert(status);alert(output);
                    }          and please reply what is alerting in status and output

Comment: @mahesh When I enter a username which is taken, status=success and output=false and output=true with unique username.

Comment: @mahesh I still get an error message whether output is true or false. It shows no matter what I enter. :(

Comment: @mahesh Just wanted to let you know that I fixed the problem! Please read the marked solution to see what we did. I really really appreciate all the replies you made to me in order to get this far. I learned so much from what you were asking me to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, But I find the easiest solution just return true or false after encoding into json through php.

```
if ($users->username_exists())
{
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
}else{
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your server side script, try returning `true` or `false` instead of `available` and `notavailable`, as both of those strings are equivalent to `true`.

Comment: @minboost Yes, I actually tried this but it didn't change the result. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you check if your PHP page is returning correctly? And are you returning sure you're returning STRINGS of 'true' and 'false'? If you try to echo booleans it will return 1 or (blank).

Comment: @minboost yes, the original JS code worked correctly but was convoluted. So I'm positive the PHP code functions as it should but something will likely need to be changed for the new jQuery version. I just don't know what that is yet.

Comment: I would use `remote:` instead of making a new method. The method probably returns a value (NULL) before the ajax finishes. JS functions using ajax don't wait for the result before continuing to process.

Comment: Also, your PHP file is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @minboost After reading, I agree that `remote:` is probably the right method, but I still am having issues getting this script to work properly. How would I write the same ajax method as remote? The biggest problem is including the data parameter in the `remote:` function. Also, how do i rewrite this to protect against SQL injection? That's more advanced than I know how to correct. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

My code:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    EMAIL: {
      remote: {
        type: "post",  
        url: "checkMail.php",           
        data:{checkUsername:function(){return $("#EMAIL").val()}            
        }
      }
    }
  },messages:{EMAIL:{remote: "Already taken!"}}
});
```