# I'd like to return the given value of an input after I've typed something into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

For some reason, I cannot figure out how to return the value of an input after I've typed something into it. This is in relation to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117901/how-can-i-force-jquery-validate-to-check-for-duplicate-username-in-database) and I'm not able to validate anything without the username value being recognized. I'm running jQuery 1.6.1 and Validate 1.8.1.

Here's the form HTML:

```
<form class="cmxform" action="register.php" method="post" name="signup" id="signup">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="username">Username: <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="Username" size="20" class="required" placeholder="Username" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

Before submitting the form, I want to make sure I can see the value of the username I type into the input. I have an alert that returns the value of the username, but the alert always shows nothing. Here's the JS code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var username = $("#username").val();
var parameter = "action=checkusername&username="+username;

$.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability",function(value,element){
    $.ajax({
          url: "dbquery.php",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          data: parameter,
          success: function(output) {
                     alert (username);
                     return true;
         }
     });
},"Sorry, this user name is not available");

// jQuery Validation script
    $("#signup").validate( {
        rules: {
            Username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                checkAvailability: true // remote check for duplicate username
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Username: {
                required: "Enter a username"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Should I be using something other than `val()` to get the value of the username? I'm so confused why it's not giving me the value that I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are hard coding username at the beginning of your javascript.  do it inside the addMethod success call

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability",function(value,element){
  var nameAvailable = false;
  $.ajax({
      url: "dbquery.php",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: "action=checkusername&username="+value,
      success: function(output) {
        //server returns whether username is valid or not
        //if it is valid set nameAvailable to true like so:
        nameAvailable = true;
      }
  });

  return nameAvailable;

});

$("#signup").validate({
  username: {
    required: true,
    checkAvailability: true
  },
  messages: {
    username: {
      required: "Username is required",
      checkAvailability: "Sorry, this user name is not available"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20" class="required checkAvailability" placeholder="Username" />
```

putting it where you have it now means that when the page loads it immediately grabs the value in the username text field, which will be empty.

EDIT:

changed the code a little to work correctly

EDIT: [jsfiddle of above code](http://jsfiddle.net/WPwnC/)

Comment: @pthurlow Turns out for my example, I had to also modify `type: "GET"` for this to work properly. Thank you.

Comment: cool, i modified the code a little more.  i think this way makes the most sense.  note that there is another class on the input called checkAvailability

Comment: @pthurlow Nice, that's awesome. It appears the line `return nameAvailable` breaks it so that nothing shows up whether it's `true` or `false`.

Comment: @pthurlow When `nameAvailable = false`, only then do I see the `messages: checkAvailability: "Sorry, this usern name is not available"` message. When `nameAvailable = true`, I see nothing. Also, if the validation error message is in `messages:`, does it need to also still exist at the end of `addMethod`?

Comment: so the value of nameAvailable determines whether the message is shown or not.  therefore, when nameAvailable is true, that means your server code determined that the username is available.  checkout this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WPwnC/ and change isNameAvailable from "true" to "false" to switch between a valid and invalid username.  also, yes you don't need the text after addMethod.  ill edit that out, thanks

Comment: @pthurlow Thank you so much for the detail. Your username solution brought me a step closer. I just need to kinda play with your code and see if it makes everything else work. I can't seem to make it function properly, even with your changes. Using `checkAvailability` in `messages:` overwrites something in the validate script that i don't want it to overwrite. Also, once I write one username, erase it and try to write another, it performs validation on every keystroke and that makes it tough to use the input. So, while I'm closer, it's not completely there yet.

Comment: @pthurlow "Something in the validate script" is the `minlength` messages saying how many characters a username needs. Even when I include a `minlength` property in `messages:`, it never shows. Sorry, should have included that.

Comment: i think the "it performs validation on every keystroke" is a feature of the validator plugin.  there might be a way to turn it off.  and if you are also including a minlength check, make sure to add a minlength class to the input element

Comment: @pthurlow `minlength` doesn't validate so that's why I'm using jQuery insted. The keystroke issue doesn't appear until after I've typed my initial username and then try to change it or update it. It's possible the `ajax()` code is making it more aggressive than it should but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @pthurlow Thank you again for helping me out with this. It ended up that I used the `remote:` method instead of `addMethod` because of other problems. I was literally banging my head against the wall because of this but you helped me learn a lot with your answer and feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

*$.val()* is fine on `<input>s`.
Give us a link ? Maybe we can see it there ?

Also, the "for" attribute should be *username* if the id really is *username* and not *uname*.

And since you're giving *$.ajax* an already stringified string, try adding also *processData: false*

Comment: oops, I fixed that misspelling for username. `processData:false` didn't correct the problem, sadly. And I would give a link but it's an NDA project that I can't show to anyone, sadly.