# How do I define the value of an input for a remote check of existing values (username)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

This is using jQuery 1.6.1 and Validate 1.8.1.

I have been banging my head against a wall because of this problem, and now I'm trying the other approach to try and solve this problem. I need to query the database for existing usernames so that someone signing up doesn't register the same one again.

HTML:

```
<form class="cmxform" action="register.php" method="post" name="signup" id="signup">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="username">Username: <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="Username" size="20" class="required" placeholder="Username" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

This time, I'm trying to use the remote function for the validate script:

```
    $("#signup").validate( {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        rules: {
            Username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                remote: {
                    url: "dbquery.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    data: "action=checkusername&username="+username,
                    success: function (output) {
                            return output;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Username: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                remote: jQuery.format("Sorry, {0} is not available")
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

The code in question that doesn't work is `var username = = $("#uname").val();`. Firebug gives the error `missing : after property id`.

I'm including the mentioned variable above inside `validate()` because I only want the value of the input after I've typed something into it, not upon loading of the page.

The other problem I've been running into is making the remote error message ONLY show up when a username already exists in the database. Unfortunately, it shows up whether dbquery.php comes back as `true` or `false`. If I try an existing username, it returns `false`, then I rewrite a new username that returns `true`, the message doesn't go away. Similarly, when I write a username and it returns `true`, I still get the remote error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why the double '=' in var username = = $("#username").val(); ?

Comment: @andy that was a mistake, I've corrected it.

Comment: Ok, put the "var username.." above the "$('#signup').validate"

Comment: @andy Right, the reason I can't do that is because the username variable will be detected as the page loads up. I must include it within `validate()` so that it detects the new data in the input itself. Keeping it outside the `validate()` means I'm hardcoding the value of the username input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [How can I force jQuery Validate to check for duplicate username in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117901/how-can-i-force-jquery-validate-to-check-for-duplicate-username-in-database)

The solution is to use the `remote` property:

Example with `remote`:

```
$("#signup").validate( {
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            remote: {
                url: "dbquery.php",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    action: function () {
                        return "checkusername";
                    },
                    username: function() {
                        var username = $("#username").val();
                        return username;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

To set a custom error message your PHP file must return the message instead of false, so `echo "Sorry, this user name is not available"` in your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var username = $("#uname").val();
```

instead of

```
var username = = $("#uname").val();
```

You can't have `= =`, it's a syntax error.

Also, make sure you properly 'escape' $("#username").val().
If someone enters: `myname&action=dosomethingelse` I'd give it a fair change it will `dosomethingelse`.

New answer:

```
$("#signup").validate( {
    var username = $("#username").val(); // -- this is wrong
    rules: {
        Username: {
            required: true,
      ...
});
```

You can fix this the easy way by just not declaring the variable at all since you're only using it is one place, but that's no fun :D

The solution is a closure:

```
$("#signup").validate( (function () {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    return {
        rules: {
            Username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                remote: {
                    url: "dbquery.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    data: "action=checkusername&username="+username,
                    success: function (output) {
                            return output;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Username: {
                required: "Enter a username",
                remote: jQuery.format("Sorry, {0} is not available")
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    };
}()));
```

(I haven't tested it, there may be a typo or syntax error).
If you have no idea what this does or why, don't worry about it :D

Comment: @frits-van-campen Can you explain how I can properly "escape" this? I don't completely understand what you mean.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can't have anything besides data in a `{}` block - I'll change my answer.

Comment: Actually .. my solution might not have the intended result because there is another flaw in your code. The `.validate` likely gets executed on page load. Guess what the value of `username` will be? _Always_ empty string. I'm guessing that's the case here ..

Comment: @frist-van-campen Well crap, is this really that complicated? I was using the `addMethod` before when a couple of people said I should use this method, but I can't get EITHER to work. You can see in my profile two other stackoverflow pages which I've created because of this problem. And you are right about your initial solution, it does return an empty string. :(

Comment: Yep. Since your validation function is _dynamic_ (it changes when the value of `#username` changes) you can't use `.validate` this way. I'm not familiar with the validate library, perhaps there is a way to have dynamic validation functions?

Comment: @frits-van-campen I appreciate the feedback. That leaves me right back where I was before, banging my head against the wall! lol Could you possibly give me feedback about the original method I was trying using `addMethod`? I'm completely stuck and frustrated beyond belief! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117901/how-can-i-force-jquery-validate-to-check-for-duplicate-username-in-database